# FileNotFoundError trying to use selenium and webdriver to automate responses to form on google

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate some responses to a Google Form (I am trying to do something based on this model: youtu.be/BvU7qfdrqjc (25 sec video); this video shows more. youtu.be/MUxScr-p-jl). I was testing this code and an error occurred:

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

print(driver.title())

print(driver.current_url())
```

**What I typed in Windows Command Prompt:**

`C:\Users\localuser>python C:\Users\localuser\Desktop\webdriver_test.py`

*C:\Users\localuser\Desktop\webdriver_test.py is a Note with the above code*

**The error message it returned:**

```
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\localuser\Desktop\webdriver_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home'''
```

Comment: `chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH` error means you need to add the chromedriver location to the PATH environmental variable. Have you downloaded chromedriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Step1***: Checkout the version of chrome you are using. Go to Chrome settings and Then click on **About Chrome**. Check version.

***Step2***: Go to, [ChromeDriver Downlaod](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Install the same driver matching the version of the chrome you are using.

***Step3***: Then extract the executable to the directory of your python file. Then try to execute again.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")

print(driver.title)

print(driver.current_url)
```

Also you do not need the parenthesis after you call to extract the properties like "title" and "current_url" since it is a string and you are trying to use it as a function. Look the last two print lines.